# Why is this.defaultNumber undefined? Trying to understand IIFE

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
const numberManipulator = (function() {
   this.defaultNumber = 5;

  const doubleNumber = function(num) {
    console.log(this.defaultNumber);
    return num !== undefined ? num * 2 : new Error('no number provided!');
  }

  return {
    doubleNumber
  }
})();

const test = numberManipulator.doubleNumber(20);
```

Why is `console.log(this.defaultNumber` showing `undefined` but if I `console.log(defaultNumber`, it shows `5`?  I thought that it would show undefined for the latter.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect *this* to be?

Comment: I expected it to be the context of the IIFE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?s=2%7C3.5902)

When the IIFE is called, its *this* is not set so it defaults to the global object, so in:

```
const numberManipulator = (function() {
   this.defaultNumber = 5;
...
})();
```

`this.defaultNumber = 5` creates a property of the global (window in a browser) object called *defaultNumber* and assigns it a value of 5.

If the return statement should really be:

```
return {doubleNumber: doubleNumber}
```

then the IIFE returns an object reference to *numberManipulator*. When called as:

```
numberManipulator.doubleNumber(20)
```

then *this* within *doubleNumber* is *numberManipulator*, which doesn't have a *defaultNumber* property so `this.defaultNumber` returns *undefined*.

Comment: Thanks RobG this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Long story short:**

<s>1. The IIFE is executing in the ***context of the `window`*** I was wrong,
 see RobG's comment.</s>
2. `this` thus refers to the `window` inside the IIFE, since it is not set by default.
3. Your doing `this.defaultNumber = 5;` is hence equivalent to
 `window.defaultNumber = 5;`
4. The second method executes in the context of `numberManipulator` and so logging `this.defaultNumber` is equivalent to `numberManipulator.defaultNumber` which was never set by you. Hence, it is undefined.

**Explanation on `this`:**

Inside any function, the `this` keyword refers to the ***current context*** in which the function is executing. It doesn't matter where you defined that function inside your codebase. All it matters in what context are you calling it. In your current case, you're calling the IIFE in the context of the window. Doing:

```
const numberManipulator = (function() {
   // MAGIC
})();
```

amounts to:

1. running an IIFE in the `window` context.
2. assigning the result it returned to a constant.

However, the context of a function may be changed by using `.call`, `.apply`, or by simply calling that method as a property of another object. In your second log, `this.defaultNumber`, `this` refers to the object since you called the method using `numberManipulator.doubleNumber(20);`. Calling methods using `object.prop()` sets their context (`=this`) to that `object`.

Hope that helps! :D

Comment: Your logical connection between 1 and 2 is flawed. All code is executed in either a global, function or eval context. How *this* is set is irrelevant to the execution context, except for arrow functions which adopt the *this* of their enclosing context. Running the IIFE in a function context would still resolve *this* to the global object (except in strict mode, where it would resolve to *undefined* regardless of the context). See [*ECMA-262: Execution Contexts*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts)

Comment: @RobG Oh, sorry. Thanks for the info. I edited my answer.